# Eclipselink - using primary key in equals

Tags: hibernate, eclipselink, equals, hashcode

I've read a lot of interesting articles about whether or not use a primary key attribute in an Eclipselink entity.

Which if the prefered way of using it; by field access or by getter acces? E.g.

```
public boolean equals(..) {
 //some code to check class, null, etc.
 if (this.id != other.id)
    return false;
}
```

or

```
public boolean equals(..) {
 //some code to check class, null, etc.
 if (this.getId() != other.getId())
    return false;
}
```

I've read that Hibernate (or at lease previous versions) used proxy objects, thus this.id could result in null even if this.getId was not null.
Is the same holds for Eclipselink as well?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: If you are using entity graphs or lazy basic mappings, yes, it would be true, but not likely for an ID- the ID always needs to have been fetched.  Still safer to use the accessor though as a general principle.

Comment: Exactly what does "not likely" means? :-)

Comment: It means it is provider specific, and providers are free to do silly things.  But since the getReference call provides the ID, even a proxy object should have the ID populated.  EclipseLink will eagerly load the ID values in an Entity, but the best way to find out is to see what EclipseLink generates for your entities..